# How to open personal hotspot page in setting programmatically(Android-studio)?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

I want to open this screen for users using intent.

I found an intent which is opening a previous of it.
**(com.android.settings.TetherSettings)**

I don't know what to add after this ***"TetherSettings.????"*** to open the below page.

[image: Personal Hotspot screen in setting]

Answer (score 0):

Swipe "Down" on the top bar, you can enable the hotspot in the short cuts in that menu some phones require 2 swipes down. if you need further control that option is in setting panel that can be found in the app drawer then head to network and connections and there should be an option for the hotspot there. There are advanced settings in the hotspot where you may control the password, name and security type. That is all i am able to provide with the information you have provided here. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thx...
Bt I am asking about coding help...